# htaccess rewrite 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an old wordpress blog that I need to redirect all posts to a new system but the url is slightly different, where the day of the post is removed. For example, the old url is like this:

```
http://www.myolddomain.com/2012/11/30/the-title-of-my-post/
```

But the new url is like this:

```
http://www.mynewdomain.com/blog/2012/11/the-title-of-my-post
```

I'm having a hell of a time getting it to rewrite correctly. I keep getting the message that the url is not found (404) but on the old server. So it's not redirecting. Here's my current htaccess entry:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([0-9]+)$/([0-9]+)$/([0-9]+)$/([0-9]+)$ http://www.mynewdomain.com/blog/$1/$2/$4[R=301,L]
```

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/$ http://www.mynewdomain.com/blog/$1/$2/$4 [R=301,L]
```

The `$` symbol (that means, `end`) should be appended only at the end (if necessary!).

Tested [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be) and it works.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! I knew it had to be something simple I just couldn't see.